# Updating the mysql database with varying number of text boxes

Tags: php, mysql, textbox, while-loop

I have multiple text boxes displaying a string corresponding to a row in the mysql database. I want to be able to change each string in the database by typing in the textbox and clicking submit.

So I create my text boxes with a while loop after connecting to the DB.

```
<form action="<?php $self ?>" form method="post">

<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY table.ID DESC";  

$result = @mysql_query($query) or die(' 
ERR: The database returned an unexpected error. 

');   

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$change="";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$post=mysql_result($result,$i,"post");
$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
$ts=mysql_result($result,$i,"timeStamp");


$page = html_entity_decode($post);

$output = stripslashes($page);

if ($output != "") { 
echo '<textarea name="' . $id . '" rows="4" cols="70">' . $output . '</textarea><div class="time"><font face="monospace">' . $ts . '</font></div>';
} //creates tables for each filled entry with a name corrsponing to its auto-increment id.

$i++;
}

?>

<input name="send" type="hidden" />  
<div class="mod">
<p><input class="master" type="submit" value="Mod" /></p></div><!--submit button is called "Mod"-->

</form>

</body>  
</html>
```

Everything displays properly. If the database has 4 rows with text in them than it will display those 4, each in a separate text box.

Now I want to replace the text in the database with whatever the user enters in the text boxes. This is the code I tried. It does nothing.

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
$post=mysql_result($result,$i,"post");

if (!isset($_POST[$id])) {
$_POST[$id] = "";
}

$change = $_POST[$id]; 

mysql_query("UPDATE  'database'.'table' SET  'post' =  '$change' WHERE  'table'.'ID' ='$id';");

$i++;
}
```

Basically the loop will run once for every row in the table. For every text box, it should UPDATE 'database'.'table' with $_POST[1] for 'post' with ID '1', $_POST[2] for 'post' with ID '2', etc...
Instead nothing happens.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use prepared statements. Your code is insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Prowla mentioned , you should use PDO instead of mysql_ functions.
Anyway, I improved your code and it suppose to work now:

```
<form action="<?php $self ?>" form method="post">
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY table.ID DESC";  
$result = @mysql_query($query) or die('Query error:'.mysql_error());   
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
$change="";

while($post = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    /*
        $post = array(
            'post' => '....',
            'ID' => '...',
            'timeStamp' => '...'
        );
    */

    $page = html_entity_decode($post['post']);
    $output = stripslashes($page);

    if ($output != "") { 
        echo '<textarea name="posts['.$post['ID'].']" rows="4" cols="70">' . $output . '</textarea><div class="time"><font face="monospace">' . $post['timeStamp'] . '</font></div>';
    } //creates tables for each filled entry with a name corrsponing to its auto-increment id.

}

?>

<input name="send" type="hidden" />  
<div class="mod">
<p><input class="master" type="submit" value="Mod" /></p></div><!--submit button is called "Mod"-->

</form>

</body>  
</html>
```

**The php update file:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY table.ID DESC";  
$result = @mysql_query($query) or die('Query error:'.mysql_error());   
while($update_post = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $update = (isset($_POST[$update_post['ID']])) ? $_POST[$update_post['ID']] : "";
    if($update != "")
    {
            mysql_query("UPDATE  'database'.'table' SET  'post' =  '$update' WHERE  'table'.'ID' ='".$update_post['ID']."';");  
                echo "<!--POST ID ".$update_post['ID']." been updated-->\n";
    }
}
```

I added an html comment (`<!-- -->`) so you can check if the update actually takes place.
This way you can debug your code. (you should also read about print_r , var_dump)

Comment: Thank you! and I will use prepared statements from now on.